# How do I hide the window border in PotPlayer?

Tags: windows-7, daum-pot-player

I have been using PotPlayer for years now (form before the name change) but recently installed it on a new system and I can not for the life of me work out how to hide the window border. I know it can do it, as I have my other system running it and the border is completely hidden.. and they are both running the same version.

**How do I set PotPlayer to hide the window border?**

Answer (score 16):

Right click on the player, "Skins", "Hide main window skin while video screen is active"

Comment: This worked for me. Why the downvotes?

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbavg.jpg) Also you need do this...