# PotPlayer (Default skin): Can I hide unnecessary buttons from controls?

Tags: daum-pot-player

Is there a way to hide these buttons?

[image]

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/985388/436846

Comment: @Eftekhari What's that?

Comment: Would help if you want to remove buttons

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but ... yes, there is a way of doing that, if you have some basic XML or image editing understanding. A PotPlayer skin (in your case the default skin, aka the `Default.dsf` file located in `c:\Program Files (x86)\DAUM\PotPlayer\Skins` folder - or if you installed PotPlayer to a different folder, `[PotPlayer installation folder]\Skins` folder) is just a simple zip file. If you want to remove those buttons, you'd have to:

- close PotPlayer
- make a backup of the `Default.dsf` file above by copying it to a safe location, in case something goes wrong (if that's the case, you'll just have to copy it back again to `[PotPlayer installation folder]\Skins` folder from the location where you backed it up)
- temporarily rename the `Default.dsf` file (not the backup, but the one you're going to modify) to something like `Default.zip` and unpack its contents
- modify the related XML/TXT file(s) in the unpacked skin contents to either remove those buttons completely or, if there are images there, edit those images to make the buttons "invisible" (e.g. draw a background color rectangle over the text or just erase the text - but be aware that if you only edit the relevant images, the buttons would still exist and respond to commands, although they'll be "invisible")
- repack the previously unpacked skin contents (now modified in the previous step) back to `Default.zip` by overwriting the original zip and its original contents
- rename the `Default.zip` back to `Default.dsf` and test if it works in PotPlayer by running the application

I did some "research" for you in this and it turns out that you'd basically have to modify the `BottomVideo.txt` file in the unpacked skin contents to do what you wanted to (just search for the string `360` in the file and you'll find the XML part that deals with those buttons). Good luck, if you're still interested!

That's all. I did such editing when making my own PotPlayer skin a couple of years ago and it turned out well enough to post it [here](https://yincognyto.deviantart.com/art/PotPlayer-skin-WMP-11-Zedd-288980254). By the way, I'm going to modify this default PotPlayer skin too (and yes, I'll remove those buttons as well), but I'll do it later on.